# Need a regex for a specific relative path

Tags: regex, validation, url

Im trying to create a regex for a particular url validation function. Got the following pseudo string that must succeed:

```
/images/uploads/[exactly 2 alphanumeric chars]/[any amount of alphanumeric chars, inc - ][.jpg or .gif or .png, case insensitive, no exceptions]
```

Must start with a / for a relative path. Should/must not contain & ? : < > etc (to avoid hacking/scripting etc) Must not contain HTTP or variants.

Comment: This is not a place where you rant to people that know they can't do this 1 minute free points task. Go somewhere else if you don't like free points.

Comment: @FlorianMertens if it is 1 minute free points task, why don't you go and do it yourself rather than creating a post and then ranting yourself?

Comment: @AmitJoki You need to read the question: 1. I am asking, not ranting, and 2. I said I can't do this (regexes).

Comment: @FlorianMertens ranting as in previous comment. I read your question and it's quite easy in regex, and WE DEFINITELY WANT TO HELP YOU BUT JUST EXPECT YOU TO SHOW SOME EFFORTS FROM YOUR SIDE.

Comment: @AmitJoki No, that's actually called defending, actually in response on a previous rant, which was agressing the question. Your comment, however, is ranting about my inability. This comment is also not ranting, its called correcting.

Comment: @FlorianMertens you got your answer. I'm done.

Comment: @AmitJoki And Im done too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
^/images/uploads/[A-Za-z]{2}/[A-Za-z0-9-]*(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)
```